# Puedo utilizar un ciclo FOR en mi programa?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa que capture nombres y calificaciones, se deben capturar 3 calificaciones por nombre y despues imprimir el nombre junto con el promedio de sus 3 calificaciones. Mi pregunta es. Se puede usar un ciclo for y arreglos para almacenarlas en una sola variable en lugar de varias como cal1, cal2, y cal 3 y no estar poniendo SOP ("Ingrese la calificacion"); tres veces?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Calificaciones{
   public static void main (String[]args){
      Scanner entrada;
      entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner entrada2;
      entrada2=new Scanner(System.in);


      String[]nombre= new String[100];
      int opcion_menu=0; int ejecutar=0; 
      int salir=0;
      int promedio;  
      int otro=0;
      int auxpromedio;
      int otro_calif;
      int a=0;
      int x=0;
      int calificacion[]= new int[100];
      int segunda[]=new int[100];
      int tercera[]=new int[100];

      do{


         System.out.println("Elija la opcion deseada \n [1].Captura \n [2].Consulta \n [3].Salida ");
         opcion_menu=entrada.nextInt();

         if(opcion_menu>3)
         {
         System.out.println("Favor de ingresar otra opcion del 1 al 3");
         }
         }while(opcion_menu>3 || opcion_menu<1);

         if(opcion_menu==1)

         {

         a++;
            System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del alumno:");
        nombre[a]=sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();

           do{
            System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion:");
            calificacion[a]=entrada.nextInt();
            if(calificacion[a]>=11)
            {
            System.out.println("ERROR \n Ingresa un valor no mayor de 10");
            }
         }while(calificacion[a]>10 || calificacion[a]<1);
        }

            System.out.println("Deseas Ingresar otros datos? \n 1.Si \n 2.No");

       if(opcion_menu==3)
         {

              System.out.println("¿Desea salir del programa? 1. Si 2. No");
           salir=entrada.nextInt();


               System.exit(0);
              System.out.println("Gracias por usar el programa");
              }

   }
}
```

Comment: no confundir java con javascript, edite tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero de todo, con un solo Scanner puedes obtener todos los datos, de esta forma con declarar `Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);`sería suficiente. Una posible solución a tu problema sería:

```
package clicloFor;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calificaciones {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Declaro el Scanner para poder pedir datos */
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    /* Declaro los arrays */
    String[] nombres = new String[100];
    int[] cal1 = new int[100];
    int[] cal2 = new int[100];
    int[] cal3 = new int[100];
    int i = 0;

    /* Entramos al buble principal del programa */
    boolean salir = false;
    while(!salir){
        System.out.println("Por favor introduzca la opcion deseada:");
        System.out.println("\t1) Insertar nuevo alumno");
        System.out.println("\t2) Consultar promedio de los alumnos");
        System.out.println("\t3) Salir del programa");
        int opcion = entrada.nextInt();
        entrada.nextLine(); /* Limpiamos el buffer */
        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:         /* A partir de 100 alumnos el programa fallaria asi */
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del alumno");
            nombres[i] = entrada.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce la calificacion 1");  /* NO PUEDO USAR UN BUCLE       */
            cal1[i] = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Introduce la calificacion 2");  /* PORQUE LOS DATOS SE GUARDAN */
            cal2[i] = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Introduce la calificacion 3");  /* EN ARRAYS DISTINTOS          */
            cal3[i] = entrada.nextInt();
            float promedio = (cal1[i] + cal2[i] + cal3[i]) / 3;
            System.out.println(nombres[i].toUpperCase() + " - " + promedio);
            i++;/* Aumentamos el indice */
            break;
        case 2:
            /* Recorremos todos los alumnos actuales */
            for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++){
                promedio = (cal1[j] + cal2[j] + cal3[j]) / 3; /* La variable no se declara ya que existe del case 1 */
                System.out.println(nombres[j].toUpperCase() + " - " + promedio);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            salir = true;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Opcion desconocida");
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Antes de terminar el programa cerramos el Scanner */
    entrada.close();
}

}
```

Pero claro, en este ejemplo (que es como tu código) no se puede usar un bucle for ya que se usan 3 arrays distintos para almacenar las notas (en mi version yo conservo todas las notas de los alumnos, por lo que podría recuperar cal2 de un alumno si quiero algo que creo que tu código no contemplaba) por otro lado podríamos verlo asi:

```
package clicloFor;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calificaciones {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Declaro el Scanner para poder pedir datos */
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    /* Declaro los arrays */
    String[] nombres = new String[100];
    int[][] calificaciones = new int[100][3]; /* Ahora tenemos una matriz */
    int i = 0;

    /* Entramos al buble principal del programa */
    boolean salir = false;
    while(!salir){
        System.out.println("Por favor introduzca la opcion deseada:");
        System.out.println("\t1) Insertar nuevo alumno");
        System.out.println("\t2) Consultar promedio de los alumnos");
        System.out.println("\t3) Salir del programa");
        int opcion = entrada.nextInt();
        entrada.nextLine(); /* Limpiamos el buffer */
        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:         /* A partir de 100 alumnos el programa fallaria asi */
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del alumno");
            nombres[i] = entrada.nextLine();
            for(int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++){
                System.out.println("Introduce la calificacion " + j);   /* SI PUEDO USAR UN BUCLE       */
                calificaciones[i][j] = entrada.nextInt();
            }
            float promedio = (calificaciones[i][0] + calificaciones[i][1] + calificaciones[i][2]) / 3;
            System.out.println(nombres[i].toUpperCase() + " - " + promedio);
            i++;/* Aumentamos el indice */
            break;
        case 2:
            /* Recorremos todos los alumnos actuales */
            for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++){
                promedio = (calificaciones[i][0] + calificaciones[i][1] + calificaciones[i][2]) / 3;
                System.out.println(nombres[j].toUpperCase() + " - " + promedio);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            salir = true;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Opcion desconocida");
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Antes de terminar el programa cerramos el Scanner */
    entrada.close();
}

}
```

Donde ahora ya que tenemos una matriz si podemos generalizar y hacerlo con un bucle, espero te sirva de ayuda!